# how to count the number of words in hindi

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript file and I would like to know how to count the number of hindi words in my textarea using javascript. it counts the number of english words fine but not with hindi words. Can someone help me please?

javascript code:

```
function getDifficultSentences(p) {
    let sentences = getSentenceFromParagraph(p);
    data.sentences += sentences.length;
    let hardOrNot = sentences.map(sent => {
      let cleanSentence = sent.replace(/[^a-z|]/gi, "") + "|";
      let words = cleanSentence.split(" ").length;  // the line where the I used for counting the words
      document.getElementById("nice").innerHTML= words.toString();
      let letters = cleanSentence.split(" ").join("").length;
      data.words += words;
      sent = getAdverbs(sent);
      sent = getComplex(sent);
      sent = getPassive(sent);
      sent = getQualifier(sent);
      sent = countWords(sent);
      //sent = getComplexDigit(sent);
      let level = calculateLevel(letters, words, 1);
      if (words < 14) {
        return sent;
      } else if (words >= 14 && words< 25) {
        data.hardSentences += 1;
        return `<span class="hardSentence">${sent}</span>`;
      } else if (words >= 30) {
        data.veryHardSentences += 1;
        return `<span class="veryHardSentence">${sent}</span>`;
      } else {
        return sent;
      }
    });

    return hardOrNot.join(" ");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do anything separate for hindi font. You can still get the value of the 
textarea in same way and split by delimiter`(' ')` ahich will give an array and then use `length` to get the count

```js
document.getElementById('getCount').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let getWordCount = document.getElementById('test').value.split(' ').length;
  console.log(getWordCount)
})
```

```css
#test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='test'></textarea><button id='getCount'>Get Count</button>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. is it being blocked by another javascript function. there are many functions in the javascript file. can it be the reason?

Comment: put a debugger and check